# How to set spark consumer cache ? to fix "KafkaConsumer cache hitting max capacity of 64" error?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I am using spark-sql 2.4.1 , spark-cassandra-connector_2.11-2.4.1.jar and java8. While inserting data from kafka topic to  C*/Cassandra table data.

I am getting error:

```
 org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaDataConsumer - KafkaConsumer cache hitting max capacity of 64, removing consumer for CacheKey(spark-kafka-source-33321dde-bfad-49f3-bdf7-09f95883b6e9--1249540122-executor)
```

How to fix this issue?

> **Section 2:**

Me using below options

```
Dataset<Row> df = sparkSession
                      .readStream()
                      .format("kafka")
                      ///other options
                      .option("startingOffsets", "latest")
                      .option("retries", 1)
                      .option("linger.ms", 10)
                      .option("enable.auto.commit", false)
                      .option("failOnDataLoss", false)
                      .option("maxOffsetsPerTrigger", 500)
                   .option("spark.streaming.kafka.consumer.cache.enabled",false)
                      .load();
```

Still I am getting error:

```
 org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaDataConsumer - KafkaConsumer cache hitting max capacity of 64, removing consumer for CacheKey(spark-kafka-source-33321dde-bfad-49f3-bdf7-09f95883b6e9--1249540122-executor)
```

Comment: Can you include the whole stacktrace? How do you `readStream`? What options do you use?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you expect here but I'm sharing my thoughts.

1. `"spark.streaming.kafka.consumer.cache.enabled"` is a DStreams flag but the mentioned API + the warning message is Structured Streaming. Please don't mix it up because these are 2 totally different products.
2. Since you're using the Structured Streaming API presume that's the product what you originally wanted. Please note in Structured Streaming Kafka consumer caching can't be turned off but the cache size can be adjusted with `"spark.sql.kafkaConsumerCache.capacity"` (soft limit). FYI, in Spark 3.0 we're re-written this whole mechanism.
3. If a job hits the default 64 cache size that means at least 64 thread is trying to read the exact same Topic Partition within a single JVM. I hardly can imagine it's efficient in any way. Performance tests could find out the proper numbers.

What I suggest is the horizontal scaling (more executors can be added). Since I don't see the code itself I suggest to understand why Spark tries to read the exact same Topic Partition from so many threads and limit it.

Comment: 1. you're using SStrm API and that's the reason why you get SStrm log messages.

Comment: 2. "spark.sql.kafkaConsumerCache.capacity" increase will not fix the issue just makes it unvisible. The processing will not be effective!

Comment: 3. Without knowing the use-case, the code, the logs hard to tell anything. That will be your effort by understanding why this happens.

Comment: Well, I think it's time to read https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html and https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html

Comment: Hi Gabor, it's not obvious in the spark documentation if this capacity limit is per executor or for the entire job. 
if it's for the entire job (for all executors) then this configuration make sense.
if this limit is for every executor then I don't really understand what's the point of creating all these consumers for a single jvm.

Answer (score 1):

I think that is WARN, anyways it is documentation issue.

You can check this link https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-25466

Cache size can be adjusted with the setting `spark.sql.kafkaConsumerCache.capacity`.